# Mysql syntax errors on import

Tags: mysql, import

I need some help with mysql errors keep popping up. Some time ago I could easily export (mainly WordPress) databases from my localhost and import these (via phpmyadmin import) on the webserver to push my websites live. Since a few days I keep getting different mysql error while importing these databases..
I tried a couple of things, changing charactersets, collate settings, ... Nothing seems to work.

I'm not a DB guy, so maybe this is something easy, but I can't seem to figure it out on my own..

**Local (xampp on mac)**

```
Databaseserver
--------------
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Servertype: MySQL
Serverversie: 5.6.26 - Source distribution
Protocolversie: 10
Gebruiker: root@localhost
Karakterset van server: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

**Webserver**

```
Databaseserver
--------------
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Servertype: MySQL
Serverversie: 5.5.31 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocolversie: 10
Gebruiker: t2c_projects@localhost
Karakterset van server: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Can someone please help me out? I can give all the info needed, don't know which are relevant.. So anyone need additional info please let me know.

Any help is welcome!

**Update1:**
Errors I'm getting

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<div class="rss-widget"><ul><li><a class=\'rsswidget\' href=\'https://wordpress' at line 9
```

This error is from a database in development, I tried a fresh installation db import and then I'm getting this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `wp_termmeta` ( `meta_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `term_i' at line 11
```

I keep getting different syntax errors, I allready tried manually fixing these but they just keep me changing stuff so I'm trying to fix this core issue..

I have a suspicion it has something to do with mysql versions or character sets..

**Update2:**

So I tried fixing the first (mixed html) error, and after I removed all \' by ", I get new errors (83 errors):

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2016-03-29 10:21:45', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ' ', '', '', 'draft', 'closed', 'cl' at line 5
```

Comment: what error you are getting....

Comment: Updated my original post

Comment: try following command directly from your db server: "mysqldump -uroot -p<root_pass> your_db > backup.sql"

Comment: I rather not :) I tried doing this locally few days ago though and I was getting exact same errors as I did in phpmyadmin.. I tried using Sequel pro also, and same errors everywhere..

Answer (score 0):

It simply seems that your SQL statements are mixed with HTML at some point

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''<div class="rss-widget"><ul><li><a class=\'rsswidget\' href=\'https://wordpress' at line 9
```

If you believe that it is not the case (e.g. you insert html in rows), please add the full queries to your post, but the issue seems pretty obvious :)

Maybe that some copy/paste manipulation error led to that state.

Without checking the full statement that causes the error, can't say more at the moment..

Comment: In this case it trips over the html, but I've been exporting/importing databases for years and this has never been a problem... It even trips over fresh install of wordpress.. I can try (again) resolving these errors one by one but it can't be that I have to do this on each import/export in the future right?

Comment: So I updated original post again, I tried resolving the html error, but like I said, errors keep on coming..